# Why is an exceptional sheaf on $P^n$ locally free?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $F$ be a coherent sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^n$ with the property that $Ext^i(F,F)$ is zero for $i > 0$, and for $i = 0$ is a one dimensional vector space over the base field. Such a sheaf is said to be exceptional.

I have seen it claimed that it follows then that $F$ is locally free, but I do not see why. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: For $n=2$ it follows from Mukai's lemma, I think. Do you have a reference for the claim that this should be true for higher $n$?

Comment: @Bernie Yes. This is in Goredentsev and Rudakov Exceptional Bundles on on projective spaces here: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.dmj/1077305507 section 1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{P}^n$ is a rational homogeneous variety this follows from the fact that an exceptional sheaf is already a homogeneous bundle, see for example Proposition 2.1.4 [here](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/documenta/vol-11/11.pdf).